# Getting incorrect northing/easting in proj4 from converting Lat/long to NAD83 Maine West 1802

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude, proj, proj4js

I'm trying to convert latitude/longitude to northing and easting via proj4js.
This is the string im using to project from.

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42.83333333333334 +lon_0=-70.16666666666667 +k=0.9999666666666667 +x_0=900000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs
```

And here are the latitude/longitude coordinates:

```
44.128783,-70.201664
```

This is what I get back as  a result:

```
9650143.893240128, -51464079.10841816
```

But this is not correct. When I try to convert this back to lat/long with this tool:
https://www.earthpoint.us/stateplane.aspx
and the proper zone number 1802 - Maine West (1983)
I get incorrect response. I'm sure I'm using the right zone / project string so why is it shooting out the wrong northing and easting?

Comment: Give coordinates in lon-lat order.

Comment: That was it! Thank you @user30184 !!!